# Unable to open external ports for Express on Ubuntu, even with firewall turned off

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu

I'm having trouble opening external ports for connections when running Express on Ubuntu. I've been unable to connect to the remote host using an external IP address and port. In the past, I used Apache as a proxy and everything worked smoothly, but now I'm only using Express and I can't even open basic ports (Apache has been completely shut down).

Here's the current situation and environment settings:

1.Ubuntu 20

2.Firewall is confirmed to be turned off

3.Logged in as root and running Express

4.If I use port 80 listener, like this:

```
dotenv.config();

const port = process.env.DB_PORT; //80
const app  = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(routerIndex);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.send('ok')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log('server port on :'+ port);
})
```

I can see the execution result at http://ip, which returns "ok".

5.However, if I use a different port, such as 1166, it will fail and I cannot see the execution result at http://ip:1166. Eventually, it will time out.

6.I've also tried opening the firewall and specifying port forwarding for port 1166, like this:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow 1166/tcp
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw reload
sudo ufw status

Status: active

To Action From

3600/tcp ALLOW Anywhere
3600 ALLOW Anywhere
80/tcp ALLOW Anywhere
89/tcp ALLOW Anywhere
22/tcp ALLOW Anywhere
1166/tcp ALLOW Anywhere
3600/tcp (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
3600 (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
89/tcp (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
1166/tcp (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
```

However, I still can't open http://ip:1166 and eventually get a timeout.

I don't know how to troubleshoot the issue anymore. Can anyone provide any help? Thank any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested locally using `localhost:1166` and `netstat -tlpn` to verify it is indeed listing on the alternate ports.

Next, where is the remote system from your test system?  eg. is it on the same network, in the cloud, in another datacenter?

If its on a separate network ensure there are no firewall or routers that also need to allow access to the port.  Same goes if its in the cloud, validate the security groups are setup correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that's on an external dedicated server. When I ran a test on port 1166 from the remote host, I couldn't connect to it using http://ip:1166 on my local machine. However, when I ran curl http://localhost:1166 on the remote host terminal, I received the response correctly. So, it confirms that it's not an issue with express.